# Laravel 5.4 fetch from database for json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel-5.4, eloquent

i just want to ask since laravel 5.4 removed the fetch method... 
what would be the best alternative i can use for my code. 
Here's my code:

@php

```
    $someArray = array();
```

// Loop through query and push results into $someArray;

```
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($someArray, array(
       'title' => $row['school_name'],
       'lat' => $row['latitude'],
       'lng' => $row['longitude'],
       'description' => $row['enrollment_sy_2014_2015']
        ));

    }

    // Convert the Array to a JSON String and echo it
    $someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
    echo $someJSON;

   @endphp
```

since i need the 'title', 'lat', 'lng' and 'description' as a variable for my map.. 
Here's the code for my map: And I Hope anyone can help :))

```
function LoadMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    //Create and open InfoWindow.
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });

        //Attach click event to the marker.
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent, Laravel provides a toJson() method on your collections and models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json

You can also convert a response with the json() method.

In your case, it could be something like:

```
    foreach($collection as $item) {
        $data[] = [
            'title' => $item->school_name,
            'lat' => $item->latitude,
            'lng' => $item->longitude,
            'description' => $item->enrollment_sy_2014_2015
        ];
    }
    return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: but im trying to use these 4 strings as variables 

'title' => $row['school_name'],
       'lat' => $row['latitude'],
       'lng' => $row['longitude'],
       'description' => $row['enrollment_sy_2014_2015']

which will be used here: 

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title 

And here:
               
                infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it suits your need better now.

Comment: Hmmm... I viewed the source code since the webpage render nothing and this is what i got:

var markers =

        HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json

[{"title":"F. Bangoy NHS","lat":"7.118366409","lng":"125.653946300","description":"4927"},{"title":"F. Bustamante NHS","lat":"7.190484185","lng":"125.646700700","description":"3299"}]

    ;

Nevertheless, I would check your answer.. Thank you so much :))

Comment: I forgot that i can use echo json_encode($data); My map is now working. Thanks again @Jachinair

Comment: I don't know your code, but if you're using Laravel, I think it's better to return an HTTP response to follow the workflow of your application, rather than echoing something between two functions. But it's difficult to know why `return response()->json($data);` renders nothing in your case.

Comment: Hmmm... I was trying to figure that out.. But maybe `return response()->json($data);` gives me json but with headers. And i only need that json value and `echo json_encode($data);` satisfies me with its results, for now..